# Laravel - No query results for model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am gettin error 'No query results for model [App\User].', when i am trying to find an user with this query.

```
        if(User::where('email', '=', Request::only('email'))->firstOrFail()){
        $validator->errors()->add(...);
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

`Request::only()` will actually return an array. In your case: `['email' => 'the-value-of-email']`. Either do this:

```
User::where(Request::only('email'))->firstOrFail()
```

Or just use `Request::input()` to retrieve only the value:

```
User::where('email', '=', Request::input('email'))->firstOrFail()
```